# How can I non-manually convert a lambda that filters a grid based on the ViewModel of a POCO to a lambda for the actual POCO?

Tags: entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Somewhat long explanation needed to setup the problem:

I'm using Telerik MVC Grid component. And one thing I am trying to figure out is how to convert and pass the filtering down to my data access layer so that it can query based on the filter. Right now it has to load ALL results, then filter via the grid component, which is horrible.

Now I've asked this question: [Telerik MVC Extensions Grid - How to have the grid filter apply to initial LINQ query or get passed down to db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593552/telerik-mvc-extensions-grid-how-to-have-the-grid-filter-apply-to-initial-linq) which tells me how to take the filter parameters from the grid and convert them to a Lambda expression. However, *my grids are not being populated by the POCO class*. As pretty normal with MVC, I am using a flattened ViewModel representing the POCOs for my pages, including the index view which contains the grid. As an example. My index view for **Users** will have the grid contain a collection of `UserViewModels` which for example may have a `Public string Department {get; set;}` property. However, the actual POCO would have a `Department` object, which contains a string property `name`.

So if I use the answer in the above solution and want to filter to get departments that start with "A". It would end up with a lambda looking like this: `(x => x.Department.StartsWith("A"))`, but this won't work when passed to my data layer, what I really need is `(x => x.Department.Name.StartsWith("A"))`.

So is there anyway to do this *without* manually writing the conversions for every single grid I have? Sure since *I* know what the properties correspond to I could manually write each one, but my app has hundreds of POCOs with grids. I'm wondering if it may be possible to have some kind of mapping to say okay this property on this class corresponds to this property on this class or something. Then I can just write a mapping and a conversion function that would take the original lambda and convert it to the lambda (or would this be easier using EntitySQL?) I can pass to an EF query and have all my filtering be transformed through that.

Comment: I believe you should consider mapping grids to database views that correspond 1-1 to view models. This way the lambda expression has the chance to map to view columns which can be arbitrarily selected from any number of tables.

Comment: How do you declare a view using code first? That might be doable, but I need it to be done in EF code first. If there is a way to say this ViewModel should be a view and control that via EF mappings. That might just work.

Comment: You don't declare views in ef, you just map database views to a model in the mapping.

Comment: Well I won't really use that solution then. We don't use any sprocs or db functions and if we have to manually create views outside application code, that doesn't fit our systems workflow.

Comment: You don't create views outside. You create a new migration and inside you use `Sql(...)` to create a view. You update views in the same way.

Comment: So it can't be done using automatic migrations then. I'd have to manually migrate every time my models in the dbcontext change?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Your views won't be inferred automatically but you easily create views by hand.